# Cannot delete a project package from Gitlab using curl command: Error 403 forbidden

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

In Gitlab I have some project packages uploaded in the Package Registry. Using a curl command I am trying to delete a package with ID 12. I have ensured that the package with ID 12 exists.

I am using below curl command as explained in the [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages.html):

```
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: myPrivateTokenHere" "https://git.myCompany.com/api/v4/projects/397/packages/12"
```

This command is returning error 403 Forbidden.

The private token i am using has the following grants in GitLab:

```
Scopes: api, read_registry, write_registry
Expires: Never
Role: Developer
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it by using a Maintainer or Owner role using the following grants:

Scopes: api, read_registry, write_registry
Expires: Never